# Making an Ajax call from the console, getting error $.ajax is not a function()

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm playing around with making an ajax call from my console to a local server but I'm getting an error:

```
VM4460:1 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function(…)
```

This is my code

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/testform?q=somethingnew1'
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit - I realized what I did wrong. I was running the console on a page that didn't have jQuery running. When I switched to website that has jQuery loaded and ran the command it worked. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Where do you include the jquery

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. How do I include the jQuery?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Comment: Your code is not javascript. Its jquery, an addon for javascript. How to include jquery is good described on jquery.org

Comment: Im not shure if it is possible to run jquery in a console

Comment: I've used jQuery before, mostly for CSS selectors. For example, $('.class_name') works....wouldn't that mean I have jQuery already installed?

Comment: jQuery must be included in the HTML page you are working on. You don't install it on your computer or something.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the `JQuery` to make the `$` functions work, to check in console add the `Jquery` script dynamically and call your ajax function.

```
(function(){
  var newscript = document.createElement('script');
     newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
     newscript.async = true;
     newscript.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js';
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(newscript);
})();



url = 'http://localhost:8080/testform?q=somethingnew1'
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
});
```

Copy and paste this code in the console and check.

But, You should add the Jquery to the HTML page in which you are working on.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using a JQuery function, so you need to include JQuery in the page, if it's not already there. Run this before your code:

```
var x = document.createElement('script');
x.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

To use jQuery in console it's need to be already included to the web page (in HTML [via script tag](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/)).

If you want to use jQuery in console on any page, use next code in console:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// ... give time for script to load, then type.
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this is to first execute this script in the dev console as a whole and then it'll let you start using jquery:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery 3.4.1.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```